# Remover seleção de um Menu Strip

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho o seguinte **Menu Strip**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que quando eu passar o mouse por cima ele não ficasse com a cor azul. É apenas pra ser informativo isso e não usar como botões.

Usando `enable` o **Menu Strip** fica cinza e perde todo o sentido de eu utilizá-lo.

Comment: Não sei se deu pra entender a publicação. Você quer uma strip que seja apenas informativa?

Comment: Isso mesmo, acho que é burrice da minha parte, mas utilizei dessa forma por não saber como realizar um procedimento anterior, então fiz com Menu Strip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meu palpite é que você está procurando a classe [`ToolStripLabel`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem?view=netframework-4.7.2) que é apena um Label que pode ser usado em conjunto de um MenuStrip.

ToolStripLabel é descendente de [`ToolStripItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem?view=netframework-4.7.2) portanto pode ser adicionado a coleção [`MenuStrip.Items`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.items?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ToolStrip_Items).

Para usa-lo apenas adicione um `ToolStripLabel` a coleção `MenuStrip.Items`:

```
menuStrip1.Items.Add(new ToolStripLabel("PT Stack Overflow"));
```

Para adiciona-lo como sub item de outro [`ToolStripMenuItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem?view=netframework-4.7.2) use a propriedade [`ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownitem.dropdownitems?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ToolStripDropDownItem_DropDownItems) do item que em que quer adicioná-lo:

```
ToolStripLabel MenuLabel1 = new ToolStripLabel("PT Stack Overflow");
((ToolStripMenuItem)menuStrip1.Items[0]).DropDownItems.Add(MenuLabel1);
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, abraço :D

Answer (score 1):

Este é o comportamento esperado de um menu. Troque o componente por um `ToolStrip` e adicione um *label*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]